Using the Matter protocol over Wi-Fi
I am new to Matter. I am having trouble understanding how Matter over Wi-Fi actually actually works with regards to the actual Wi-Fi network.
If I am using Matter over Wi-Fi for all of my devices, will each and every device take up an available Wi-Fi slot on the Wi-Fi network? Hence, will I be able to see each and every matter/Wi-Fi device via the Wi-Fi router. Some Wi-Fi routers have a limit to how many Wi-Fi devices can be connected to it.
Or is it the case that the the Wi-Fi router only knows about the Matter controller on the network and not every single Matter device?
I believe Matter devices can even communicate directly with each other without going through the access point / router, so i'm curious as to how this happens exactly. Thanks in advance.

It depends on whether the Matter devices use WiFi or Thread…

@jcaron I am talking about Matter over Wi-Fi only here in this case
